# Slicing numpy array of dictionaries on key

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a machine learning project that has the data sorted into numpy arrays. The first column is the label, and the second is a dictionary of features and their values, since as a full matrix it would be very sparse and there are a significant number of features and examples.

I've found that it's fairly simple to get a subset of rows from my data set by using:

```
dataset[dataset[:, 0] == 1]
```

and this returns a numpy array of all the rows where the label is 1. What I want to do is something like this (this example does not work):

```
dataset[2 in dataset[:, 1]]
```

where it returns a numpy array of all the rows that have 2 as a key in the dictionary. Even more helpful would be a way to filter on a key-value pair (this current set is all binary features but I have other projects that have multiple possibilities).

I'm using python 3.6.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's a sample of the data I'm trying to parse:

```
[1 {10: 1, 12: 1, 15: 1, 18: 1, 31: 1, 36: 1, 48: 1, 59: 1, 70: 1, 79: 1, 90: 1, 100: 1, 125: 1, 140: 1, 163: 1, 185: 1, 200: 1}]
[1 {9: 1, 11: 1, 14: 1, 18: 1, 29: 1, 36: 1, 48: 1, 59: 1, 68: 1, 79: 1, 89: 1, 103: 1, 120: 1, 143: 1, 160: 1, 180: 1, 200: 1}]
[-1 {10: 1, 11: 1, 14: 1, 18: 1, 29: 1, 35: 1, 46: 1, 57: 1, 68: 1, 79: 1, 90: 1, 104: 1, 124: 1, 143: 1, 163: 1, 183: 1, 203: 1}]
[1 {9: 1, 11: 1, 14: 1, 18: 1, 30: 1, 35: 1, 46: 1, 57: 1, 68: 1, 79: 1, 90: 1, 103: 1, 123: 1, 143: 1, 163: 1, 183: 1, 204: 1}]
[-1 {10: 1, 12: 1, 14: 1, 18: 1, 33: 1, 36: 1, 45: 1, 56: 1, 67: 1, 78: 1, 89: 1, 100: 1, 120: 1, 140: 1, 160: 1, 193: 1, 203: 1}]
```

The first suggestion worked great, but then I realized I also slice out the rows that don't have the feature, but aside from a super slow function that gets the indices of added rows, then adds the others to another set, I can't get it to work. When I try something like:

```
helper2 = np.vectorize(not dict.__contains__)
```

it says that a "bool object is not callable".

Comment: Could you add some small sample data?

Comment: I've added a few lines of the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will not help with performance, but you can use `np.vecorize` on `dict.__contains__` to imitate numpy indexing.

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([[1, {1: 1}], [2, {2: 2}]])

helper = np.vectorize(dict.__contains__)

res = xs[helper(xs[:,1], 1)]
# array([[1, {1: 1}]], dtype=object)
```

Here, `helper` is a function of two arguments. The first argument is an `np.ndarray` of `dict`s or a `dict`. The second argument is `np.ndarray` of keys you want to test for or a single key.